# How do I fix the error conflicting types? c programming

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, conflicting-libraries

I am attempting to create a program that asks me questions but with different numbers each time so that i can practice for a school competition. This is just a simple example for one of the questions but each time I try to compile the program I get the error: conflicting types where the random float is passed to a function. I'm new at programming and don't see what went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float fixran1();
float fixran2();
int ovrall=0;
float question1();

int main()
{
    question1();
}

question1( )
{
    float a, b;
    float ran11=fixran1((((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX))*50)+25);
    float ran12=fixran2((((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX))*15)+7);
    char ques1[]="If an employee works %f hours and is paid $%f per hour, how much is their gross pay?";

printf(ques1, ran11, ran12);
scanf("%f",a);
b=ran11*ran12;

if(a==b)
{
    printf("correct");
    ovrall=ovrall+1;
}
else
    printf("incorrect, the right answer is %f", b);
}





fixran1(float ran11)
{
    float i=ran11%.1;
    ran11=ran11-i;
    return(ran11);
}

fixran2(float ran12)
{
    float i=ran12%.01;
    ran12=ran12-i;
    return(ran12);
}
```

Here are my errors:

```
 error: conflicting types for 'fixran1'
 error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'double')
 error: conflicting types for 'fixran2'
 error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'double')
```

I had no trouble doing this with ints but I can't get floats to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the return type for your functions bodies, so they are defaulting to `int` conflicting with your prototype return type `float`.

Change for example

```
question1( )
```

to

```
float question1()
```

and so on.

Also add the parameters passed to the functions in the function prototypes:

```
float fixran1(float ran11);
float fixran2(float ran12);
```

or (not necessarily needing to specify the parameter name):

```
float fixran1(float);
float fixran2(float);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.1` to `.1f` and `.01` to `.01f`.  That makes the numeric literal a `float` instead of a `double`.

Comment: Better yet, just don't use `float` in C. Ever. Just use double for everything. The number of application for `float` is actually useful is maybe 1 in 1000.